# How to use PyQT5 Table and Menu at the same time?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am learning Python GUI with PyQT5 and was trying to work with Menu and Table at the same time.  How to declare the class when I want both Menu at Menubar and a table in the output at the same time?

For Menu, I declared the class as `class Window(Wid.QMainWindow):` and it is working. For Table, I declared the class as `class Window(Wid.QWidget):` and there is also no problem with output. How to declare the class when I want both Menu at Menubar and a table in the output at the same time?

`import sys
import PyQt5.QtGui as Gui
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as Wid
import PyQt5.QtCore as Cor`

## --------Code for Menu-----------

`class Window(Wid.QMainWindow):`

```
def __init__(self):
    super(Window, self).__init__();
    self.title = "Test";
    self.iconname = "test.png";
    self.initWindow();

def initWindow(self):    
    self.setWindowTitle (self.title);
    self.setGeometry (100, 100, 500, 300);
    self.setWindowIcon (Gui.QIcon(self.iconname));

    self.qtMenu();
    self.show ();

def qtMenu(self):
    mainMenu = self.menuBar();
    fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('File');

    subFileMenuNew = Wid.QAction('New', self);
```

## --------Code for Table-----------

`class Window(Wid.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__();
        self.title = "Test";
        self.iconname = "test.png";
        self.initWindow();`

```
def initWindow(self):    
    self.setWindowTitle (self.title);
    self.setGeometry (100, 100, 500, 300);
    self.setWindowIcon (Gui.QIcon(self.iconname));

    self.qtTable();
    self.boxLayout = Wid.QVBoxLayout();
    self.boxLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget);
    self.setLayout(self.boxLayout);

    self.show ();

def qtTable(self):
    self.tableWidget = Wid.QTableWidget();
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(2);
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2);
    self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, Wid.QTableWidgetItem("First Name"));
    self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, Wid.QTableWidgetItem("Last Name"));
```

How to declare the class when I want both Menu at Menubar and a table in the output at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import sys 
import PyQt5.QtGui     as Gui 
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as Wid 
import PyQt5.QtCore    as Cor


class Window(Wid.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__();
        self.title    = "Test"
        self.iconname = "D:/_Qt/img/py-qt.png"
        self.initWindow()
# +++       
        self.tableWidget = Wid.QTableWidget(2, 2);
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, Wid.QTableWidgetItem("John"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, Wid.QTableWidgetItem("Pythonic"))    
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["First Name", "Last Name"])   # +
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tableWidget)                                   # +   
# +++

    def initWindow(self):    
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowIcon(Gui.QIcon(self.iconname))
        self.qtMenu()

    def qtMenu(self):
        self.main_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&File") 
        self.newItem  = Wid.QAction("New",  self,  triggered = self.newFile)
        self.exitItem = Wid.QAction("Exit", self, triggered = Wid.qApp.quit) 
        self.main_menu.addAction(self.newItem) 
        self.main_menu.addAction(self.exitItem)         

    def newFile(self):
        print("def newFile(self):")        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Wid.QApplication(sys.argv)
    qt_app = Window()
    qt_app.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]